# How to set the google-maps marker as it is showed on the original website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

Try to Search the first address on google maps, and click on it :

it will show us a marker with a photo (if avaiable), description, and some links.
I'd like to add the same marker in my web application.

Which API I need to use? At the moment I just make my own string and append it :

```
var finestra='';
finestra += '<div style="position:relative;width:200px;">';
finestra += '<div style="position:relative;float:left; color:#000000;" class=canale>';
finestra += 'Archimede<br />Via Brennero,12<br />38100 Trento(TN)<br />c.+39 555555555';
finestra += '</div>';
finestra += '</div>';

var marker = createMarker(map.getCenter());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(46.084989,11.118851), 16, G_NORMAL_MAP);
map.addOverlay(marker);
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(finestra);
```

But I need the same marker as google maps show on the original website.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [custom overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) . Here is an example: [custom marker](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html)

Comment: I know. But is not possible to get the default as for Google Maps?